# When using enforceAppCheck and consumeAppCheckToken with App Check for Firebase Cloud Functions do we need to check for "context.app == undefined"?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

The previous advice for using App Check with Firebase Cloud Functions was to check for the existence of the `context` argument like this:

```JavaScript
export const myFunction = functions.https.onCall(
  (data, context) => {
      if (context.app == undefined) {
        functions.logger.error(
          "The function must be called from an App Check verified app."
        );
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          "failed-precondition",
          "The function must be called from an App Check verified app."
        );
      }

      ...
  }
);
```

But [the docs now show](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions) that we can use `enforceAppCheck` and `consumeAppCheckToken` (the latter is still in Beta), which I assume does the same thing as above.

Following those new docs, the example they give looks like this:

```JavaScript
const functions = require("firebase-functions/v1");

exports.yourV1CallableFunction = functions
  .runWith({
      enforceAppCheck: true, // Reject requests with missing or invalid App Check tokens.
      consumeAppCheckToken: true  // Consume the token after verification.
  })
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
      // context.app contains data from App Check, including the app ID.
      // Your function logic follows.
      ...
  });
```

When using this new technique, can we safely skip the check for `context.app == undefined` and error throwing? Or do we still need that part?

Comment: Have you checked with this [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.https.callablecontext#properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from looking at [the code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/master/src/common/providers/https.ts#L740-L755) that interprets that new `enforceAppCheck` option indeed replaces the previous `if (context.app == undefined) {` check.